# How to use PNG images in Next.js outside the default PUBLIC directory?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-images

I saw that an alternative to be able to use images using another directory other than the Public folder, is to use the Next-Images library, but I do all the setup correctly as described in the documentation, I've seen several videos on the internet, but nothing works, I can only load it svgs.
I'm using typescript in my project.
There's a detail that I noticed regarding typing, which we have to add this reference:

```
/// <reference types="next-images" />
```

getting like this:

```js
/// <reference types="next" />
/// <reference types="next/types/global" />
/// <reference types="next/image-types/global" />
/// <reference types="next-images" />
```

To the next-env.d.ts file, however every time I run the `yarn dev` command that reference that was added is automatically deleted.

My next.config.js file:

```js
const withImages = require('next-images');

module.exports = withImages({
   inlineImageLimit: false,
   esModule:true,
});
```

Another thing I noticed is that: when the project is compiled, by the browser console the tag `<img src="">`, in the src is the path:

```
/_next/static/images/cora-c562c6fa203473521a5dc5b15a841192.jpg
```

Since there's this other path that your I manually put through the browser console, it works:

```
/_next/static/image/src/assets/cora.e76cddfc04ca9d4b8a3868b2c40e3b7f.jpg
```

So, if anyone knows if I'm missing any settings that I might not have done, or a video that might help, or a detail from the documentation, I'll be grateful.

**Next Version: 11.0.1
Typescript Version: 4.3.5
Next-Images Version: 1.8.1**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `tsconfig.json`, add `next-env.d.ts` to `exclude` array:

```json
{
  // ...
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "next-env.d.ts"],
  "include": ["**/*"]
}
```

Create a new file `custom.d.ts` and add this:

```
/// <reference types="next" />
/// <reference types="next/types/global" />
/// <reference types="next-images" />
```

In `next.config.json`:

```js
const withImages = require('next-images');

module.exports = withImages({
  images: {
    disableStaticImages: true,
  },
});
```

---

Note that using `next-images` is not required for your use case at all. Next.js now supports this out of the box. So with default configuration (a fresh `create-next-app`), you can directly do:

```js
import Image from 'next/image';
import img from '../path/to/img.png';

<Image src={img} alt="some text"/>

// or with img tag:

<img src={img.src} height="100" width="100" alt="some text"/>
```

Refer: [Image Imports](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#image-imports)